# I want to build a local application with interactive maps(ie regional maps with data being displayed when we click on a region)

Tags: java, python, user-interface, maps, gis

I want to build a local application with interactive maps(ie regional maps with data being displayed when we click on a region). An example pic is given below. I have to embed data like news events and other things as needed in the interactive map. I know a little Java and Python. How should I proceed with my ideas to create my project?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhSZS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly decide for which platform and OS you want to code. If you are going to code for Android or IOS you could simply use the google maps API and add custom markers to it. The same would be sufficient for an Web-Application, while for PC‘s I would not suggest this approach